# generating random game obstacles in swift

Tags: swift

I have made 6 obstacles of UIImage.

These obstacles has their center.x moving -5 every 0.045 second based on my "movement" function.  Therefor after sometime they are out of the picture.

I'm trying to figure out how I can make a function that regenerates these obstacles to comeback in the view from the right side and randomized, so my game keeps having obstacles scrolling in from the right side and everytime they scroll in from the right, they have a new center.y value.

Comment: It would make it easier for us to help you if you added some of your code. But...top of my mind, some sort of check in your movement function to see if center.x < 0 and if so, update center.x to be something larger than the right side of the screen and at the same time update center.y to a new random value.

Comment: I guess that would work. Seems so simple but my head has been slow today... I'll take a look at this. Thank you.

Comment: Simple is usually the best and sometimes you just need an extra set of eyes. Mind if I write an answer?

Comment: Sure, go ahead @pbodsk

Comment: Appreciate your help @pbodsk

before looking at your answer I created a solution, almost the same as yours. But I like yours more because it makes sure we clear of the screen in a more safer way. 

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top of my mind, some sort of check in your movement function to see if center.x < 0 and if so, update center.x to be something larger than the right side of the screen and at the same time update center.y to a new random value.

Some vague pseudocode:

```
if yourItem.center.x < 0 - yourItem.size.width / 2 { // to make sure we're clear of the screen
     yourItem.center = CGPoint(x: maxWidth, y: randomYPos)
}
```